# C++ LNK2019 error with constructors and destructors in derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, destructor, lnk2019

I have two classes, one inherited from the other. When I compile, I get the following errors:

> Entity.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Utility::Parsables::Base::Base(void)" (??0Base@Parsables@Utility@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Utility::Parsables::Entity::Entity(void)" (??0Entity@Parsables@Utility@@QAE@XZ)
>
> Entity.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Utility::Parsables::Base::~Base(void)" (??1Base@Parsables@Utility@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall Utility::Parsables::Entity::~Entity(void)" (??1Entity@Parsables@Utility@@UAE@XZ)
>
> D:\Programming\Projects\Caffeine\Debug\Caffeine.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

I really can't figure out what's going on.. can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm using Visual C++ Express 2008. Here are the files..

**"include/Utility/Parsables/Base.hpp"**

```
#ifndef CAFFEINE_UTILITY_PARSABLES_BASE_HPP
#define CAFFEINE_UTILITY_PARSABLES_BASE_HPP

namespace Utility
{
 namespace Parsables
 {
  class Base
  {
  public:
   Base( void );
   virtual ~Base( void );
  };
 }
}

#endif //CAFFEINE_UTILITY_PARSABLES_BASE_HPP
```

**"src/Utility/Parsables/Base.cpp"**

```
#include "Utility/Parsables/Base.hpp"

namespace Utility
{
 namespace Parsables
 {
  Base::Base( void )
  {
  }

  Base::~Base( void )
  {
  }
 }
}
```

**"include/Utility/Parsables/Entity.hpp"**

```
#ifndef CAFFEINE_UTILITY_PARSABLES_ENTITY_HPP
#define CAFFEINE_UTILITY_PARSABLES_ENTITY_HPP

#include "Utility/Parsables/Base.hpp"

namespace Utility
{
 namespace Parsables
 {
  class Entity : public Base
  {
  public:
   Entity( void );
   virtual ~Entity( void );
  };
 }
}

#endif //CAFFEINE_UTILITY_PARSABLES_ENTITY_HPP
```

**"src/Utility/Parsables/Entity.cpp"**

```
#include "Utility/Parsables/Entity.hpp"

namespace Utility
{
 namespace Parsables
 {
  Entity::Entity( void )
  {
  }

  Entity::~Entity( void )
  {
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Are all these files included in the project? Do you see them compiling?

Comment: Yes, they are all included and compile fine.

Comment: try getting rid of the namespaces

Comment: Just a c & p of an answer I posted a little futher down:
"I just checked and remembered something, I have two files both named Base.cpp, but they are in different directories. I see one compile, but not two. Could that be the problem?"

Comment: @BLH Sure. First thing to do is to be sure what you are linking. Rename any suspect file, and check the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The relevant bit is this:

```
unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Utility::Parsables::Base::Base(void)"
```

You need to provide a definition for `Base::Base` and `Base::~Base`. A declaration is not good enough. Even if you have nothing to do in either function, you need to leave an empty function body, because C++ actually requires the function to exist. C++ puts things like virtual table maintenance inside your constructors and destructors, so they must be defined even if you don't need to do anything there -- C++ has to do things in there.

Are you sure Base.cpp is being included in the build?

Comment: My source files do have definitions in them, I left an empty function body as you've described.

Comment: @BLH: Read my last sentence again :) (I edited the answer even though it doesn't appear that way)

Comment: I just checked and remembered something, I have two files both named Base.cpp, but they are in different directories. I see one compile, but not two. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @BLH: Yes, that would do it. AFAIK by default VS dumps it's object files into a single directory, each file named after the source file that gave rise to it. It's possible then for one to overwrite the other.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there any way around it or am I just going to have to rename one of them?

Comment: @BLH: In project properties: Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Object File Name. You should be able to change it there from $(IntDir) to something like $(SourceFilePath)\${SourceFileName}.obj\, though I have not tried this.

Comment: @BLH Best not to have complex directory structures (or complex namespace schemes) - they will always cause trouble, particularly when porting code.

Comment: "Are you sure Base.cpp is being included in the build?" - this part of your answer solved the problem for me, in a project that needed to know how the destructor was IMPLEMENTED. This was on a Visual studio project that depended on aonther project of the same solution, and the solution was simply Ctrl+mouse-dragging the .cpp file were the destructor to the project complaining about this.

Comment: This really helped me as I forgot to define a dtor in my derived class and it was staring me in the face but I just couldn't find the bug, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered this exact same error today in Visual Studio 2015. Unfortunately the accepted answer didn't worked (as well as answers from many same questions). The thing that worked for me was right click on the base class cpp file, exclude and then include it again. I think somehow VS got confused while moving file around and renames and it just silently refused to compile it even though it was marked as "Included In project" = true in property editor as well as listed in vcproj file in  group. This is horrible error and ended up spending good hour on it.

Answer (score 0):

Either your base.cpp is not being compiled/linked or you have a misspelling in it